# Can't Inject service in angular 2 with ASP Core 1.1

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, single-page-application

i'm using [Yeoman generator-aspnetcore-spa](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) and i'm trying to inject service into my app in Angular 2
so i added `providers: [ CommService]` in sharedConfig "app.module.shared.ts"
when i'm trying to run the app i got

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for CommService!
>   Error: No provider for CommService!

```
@Injectable()
export class CommService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }


  getUserIP() {
    return this.http.get('http://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
      .map(x => x.json());
  }

}
```

i tried  to add the service in providers in boot-server.ts 
and that's what i got

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http! (CommService -> Http)
>   Error: No provider for Http! (CommService -> Http)
>   at Error (native)

i have three module files

- app.module.shared.ts which contains

```

```
export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        LoginComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
};
```

```

- app.module.server.ts which contains

```

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        ServerModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

```
 - app.module.client.ts which contains

```

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin } 
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

```

So where i can import and inject my Services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this problem by adding the Service to app.module.client ,app.module.server  and to boot-client like this

```
const modulePromise = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {providers:[CommService]});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are using the Http service in your CommService? It would be really helpful if you also provided the CommService class you are experiencing difficulties with.

When you provide the CommService in the shared config which is used by both the server and the client, both of those need to import the HttpModule. In your case, only the client's app module imports the HttpModule. If you try to use the CommService on the server, there will be no providers for the HttpModule which i guess you are using in your CommService.

Your problem really doesn't have anything to do with asp.net as this has to do with imports/modules in Angular. https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule

Comment: yes you're right i'm using Http, i added CommService code in the question,i'm confused about the strange structure which is not exists in  normal agnualr app, server-client-shared. so i'm using CommService in client side if course and when i add it providers in  app.module.shared.ts  this returns No provider for CommService but i already added  so where is the problem? do i need to add every server to client and server file

Comment: If you are only using the CommService on the client side I would suggest providing it in the client module only, and not in the shared. This would probably also remove any errors of not having a provider for the Http service in the server module.

Comment: its the same thing when i'm add it to app.module.client i got : No provider for CommService! 

`
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
        CommService
       
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

`